# <template> initialization event with polymer.js

Tags: javascript, polymer, html5-template

Using Polymer I can use the `<template>`-tag outside of a `<polymer-element>` using the `is='auto-binding'` attribute. How can I know in Javascript however that the `<template>` has actually been initialized. I have tried listening for every possible event I could think of and browsed the source code as well for a bit, but can't seem to find any pointers anywhere although I assume this must be possible.

If what I mean is hard to comprehend a simple jsfiddle showing the issue can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ycsm51s9/), though I think the description above should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to listen for the `template-bound` event. It's mentioned at the bottom of [this section](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#autobinding).

```
<template is="auto-binding" id="tmpl">
  <input value="{{test}}">
  {{test}}
</template>

<script>
  var tmpl = document.querySelector('#tmpl');
  tmpl.test = 123;
  tmpl.addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
    console.log('template bound fired!');
    console.log(document.querySelector('input'));
  });
</script>
```

I shot [a screencast on auto-binding templates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82LfXCeuaOo&index=8&list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN) which covers this a bit more.

Comment: I feel stupid now, I actually wasn't aware auto-binding was covered in the documentation, despite having used the documentation constantly. Splitting up or somehow reorganizing those sections might make sense if you'd ask me. Either way, thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries. It can be hard to find stuff in the docs sometimes. We're always trying to improve them.